# Facebook FQL is not working anymore

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, facebook-c#-sdk

I have two entries on my wall which are both posted by me.

I like both entries, but FQL says I only like one of them!

This is working:

`https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=SELECT%20object_id%20FROM%20like%20WHERE%20object_id=180953018606782%20AND%20user_id=1161331828&access_token=XXXXXXXXX`

This is not working:

`https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=SELECT%20object_id%20FROM%20like%20WHERE%20object_id=1842987912056%20AND%20user_id=1161331828&access_token=XXXXXXXX`

Please help, because this is a big issue! Is the Facebook-Server damaged?

Comment: You'd have more luck on the http://forum.developers.facebook.net/, especially if it is a problem with Facebook.

Comment: mind sharing what are these "objects"?